# How to train a model based on an array of 3-tuples

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm kinda new to the whole machine learning topic and I would like to have to some advice, starting points:

I have an array with up to 100 entries. An entry is a 3-tupel of doubles:

e.g.

```
x: 0.01
y: 0.02
z: 0.03
```

Array example:

```
[(0.01, 0.02, 0.03), (0.01, 0.02, 0.03)]
```

I would like to train a model which outputs true or false based on the array of these 3-tuples.

```
[(0.01, 0.02, 0.03), (0.01, 0.02, 0.03), ...] => true
[(0.02, 0.021, 0.03), (0.041, 0.022, 0.035), ...] => false
```

Where would you suggest that I start? Would you use something like Caffe or Keras.

Hopefully that question is not too broad...

Comment: Few questions to start with 1. are you planning to use python or R? 2. you have o/p value of 100 entries that you mentioned?

Comment: 1) I'd like to use python, 2) what do you mean by o/p value, more examples?

Comment: You said your data is 3-tuple of doubles but the way you mentioned above it looks like list of dictionary to me.

Comment: output varaible/ dependent variable that you want to predict.

Comment: I updated my initial question, hope that makes it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to start with [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) which has a lot of power already packed into it.

A very basic example of how something like this can be done may look like this:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

np.random.seed(42)

# Generate some random data

X_train = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(X_train))

X_test = np.random.rand(2000, 3)
y_test = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(X_test))

# Train a classifier

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Test the classifier and print performance measure (here: accuracy)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
y_random = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(X_test))

print('Accuracy (pred): {:.4f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))
print('Accureary (random): {:.4f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_random)))
```

Will ouput:

```
Accuracy (pred): 0.5030
Accureary (random): 0.5210
```

Since this is all random data the example does not make any sense. However, in case your `x`, `y`, `z` tuple does have any predictive power for your target values, then you should see a higher accuracy than random.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. I'm struggling how to understand my training set(array of 3-tuples) and the correct answers(0,1,0,1 etc.)

Comment: @gabac Since I don't know your data set I cannot tell you how to interpret or understand it. All I believe at this point is that you want to train a binary classifier which decides whether something is `true` or `false` based on three input parameters - your 3-tuples. My answer is a sketch of what a solution could look like.

Comment: I think I got the hang now. Also new to python ;) Thx a lot!

Comment: One more question: Would GaussianNB also make sense if I only have x instead of x,y,z ?

Comment: @gabac I cannot tell you if GaussianNB makes sense at all. This is just one possible model you can try to fit your data. Every model makes some assumptions about your data. You'll have to learn more about it before you can chose the "optimal" model. However, you can also start by creating a list of classifiers, run and evaluate them all and see how each of them performs (e.g. logistic regression, random forrests etc.).

Comment: @gabac [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Found that as well :) Thx a lot!